# How to pass data from fragment activity to fragments

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am doing service call in `FragmentActivity` where I need to pass two datas(name and address) to Fragment A and Fragment B respectively.

Here is my code which I tried.

```
 public class C extends FragmentActivity {
// public PassDataToFragments fragmentCommunicator;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_pager);
    serviceCall();
}

void serviceCall() {
    JSONObject totalData = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject jsonData = totalData.getJSONObject("result");
    trainerStrName = jsonData.getString("name");
    trainerStrAddress = jsonData.getString("address");
    // activityCommunicator.passDataToFragment(trainerStrName); i am
    // null pointer exception
    // pass name to fragment A and address to fragment B
}

@Override
public SherlockFragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {

    // Open Previous Projects
    case 0:
        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA ();
        return fragmentA;

        // Open Certification
    case 1:
        FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB ();
        return fragmentB;

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

What I tried is I used interface but i don't know how to use and get the values of name to FragmentA and address to Fragment B:

```
 public interface PassDataToFragments {
 public void passDataToFragment(String someValue);
  }
 class Fragment A extends Fragment implement PassDataToFragment{
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trainers_certification,
            container, false);
 return view;
 }
 @Override
  public void passDataToFragment(String someValue) {
    //Log.e("string",someValue);

}
}
```

Comment: That subject is explained on the official basic training page here :http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html Have you tried following the given example ?

Comment: @Shadow : No need to use `interface`.  use parametrized class  constructor to pass data from Activity to Fragments

Comment: Shouldn't `setArgument` be a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the Activity's data by calling Activity's method from  fragment :

Get the value in Fragment :

```
String name = ((C)getActivity()).getValue();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

C Class :

```
public String getValue()
{
   return trainerStrDescription;
}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data from activity like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);
bundle.putString("address", address);
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment A `onCreateView` method retrieve it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    String name = getArguments().getString("name");    
    String address = getArguments().getString("address"); 
}
```

**EDIT**

If fragment is already loaded then you can do it like this (using your current implementation)

Send data like this

```
PassDataToFragment fragA = (PassDataToFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container); // Change the id as per yours
fragA.passDataToFragment(name, address);
```

You will get the data in `passDataToFragment()` inside fragment A.

Comment: thanks. I need to pass the bundle inside getItem method of activity?